# Вызов телефонного звонка из приложения -> Определить, когда человек взял трубку

Tags: java, android

Есть следующий фрагмент кода, вызывающий телефонный звонок:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel:***********"); // скрыл номер телефона
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

И вот такой фрагмент, который определяет, когда принимающий вызов человек отключает соединение (кладёт трубку):

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
        String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
    } else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
        // Действия при закрытии соединения
    }
}
```

В итоге телефонный звонок имеет следующие "стадии":

1. Звонок (Ожидание соединения)
2. Подошли к телефону (Соединение установлено)
3. Положили трубку (Соединение закрыто)

Как сделать определитель на подобии этого, который будет определять когда приложение только начало звонить человеку (ожидание соединения), а когда уже дозвонилось (соединение установлено)?

P.S. Я думаю, я понятно объясняю :D